# How can I change class based states into function based if its more than one property?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am trying to change class based components to function based.

its easy if its only one property, like `state = { value:1}  const[value,setValue] = React.useState(1);`

but if its more than one, i am in stuck since i am new to this programming language.

```
    state = {
        userToken: {
          email: '',
          password: ''
        },
        baseEmptyData: {
          receiptID: -1,
          processID: 0,
          receiptName: "",
          image: "",
          hasImage: 0,
          inputs: {
            companyName: '',
            fisNo: '',
            fisTarihi: '',
            vd: '',
            vdNo: ''
            },
          userData: {
            name: '',
            surname: '',
            email: '',
            accountType: '',
            remaining: 0,
            quota: 0,
            corporate: '',
            apiKEY: '',
            apiURL: '',
         },
```

how to change this? should i write something like
`const [userData, setUserData] = useState([name:"",surname:""])` true?

How to change baseEmptyData-inputs part to function base?

Comment: Try taking a look at [useReducer](https://it.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer)

Comment: For a simple translation I would totally go `const [userData, setUserData] = useState({name:"",surname:"",...})`. Just remember to keep your state object immutable. If you want to update it just create a copy and set that on state.

Comment: Couldnt I do this with `const[ x, setX] `?

Comment: @windowsill thanks. How about to reach input part thats in baseEmptyData? Can i do it like `const [baseEmptyData, setBaseEmptyData] = useState({inputs: {companyName:"", vd:""}})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you will want to break your state up into manageable chunks of related data, for at least a couple reasons:

1. Smaller chunks of related state values are easier to work with and reason about.
2. Unlike class-based component's `this.setState`, functional component state ***is not*** shallowly merged, you need to manage this yourself.

With class-based components you were limited to one single state object, `this.state`, but there is no such restriction in functional components, you can use as many `useState` hooks as necessary to represent your component state.

For your provided class-based state, I see a good division between `userToken` and `baseEmptyData`. I would create a state for each and since `baseEmptyData` looks like static initial "state" this can be declared external to a component and consumed.

```
const initialBaseEmptyData = {
  receiptID: -1,
  processID: 0,
  receiptName: "",
  image: "",
  hasImage: 0,
  inputs: {
    companyName: '',
    fisNo: '',
    fisTarihi: '',
    vd: '',
    vdNo: ''
    },
  userData: {
    name: '',
    surname: '',
    email: '',
    accountType: '',
    remaining: 0,
    quota: 0,
    corporate: '',
    apiKEY: '',
    apiURL: '',
  },
};
```

In component

```
const [userToken, setUserToken] = React.useState({
  email: '',
  password: ''
});
const [baseEmptyData, setBaseEmptyData] = React.useState(initialBaseEmptyData);
```

Since the `baseEmptyData` is a bit bigger, more complex, and has nested properties, you may find it easier to use the [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) hook instead.

> `useReducer` is usually preferable to `useState` when you have complex
> state logic that involves multiple sub-values or when the next state
> depends on the previous one. `useReducer` also lets you optimize
> performance for components that trigger deep updates because you can
> pass dispatch down instead of callbacks.

Comment: Thank you Sir, so is it possible to do `const [baseEmptyData, setBaseEmptyData] = React.useState(initialBaseEmptyData);` since it also includes other properties, i thought we couldnt do it. I will search about useReducer too,

Comment: Can i do it like const [baseEmptyData, setBaseEmptyData] = useState({inputs: {companyName:"", vd:""}})

Comment: @user15775693 Yes, and yes. You can specify a reference to an object value, an object literal, and even use a function to initialize your state (see [lazy initialization](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state)).

Comment: Thank you a lot. Do I have any chance to ask you more questions when I have? i just got my first tech job, and im expected to use React-Native and change class based project to function based, even though i just know basic things... I am trying.    Could you offer any resource for me to learn, should i watch tutorials?(i think its time consuming... and i get bored after some time, or i just should follow original documentation? but since i am beginner, it seems so hard for me to do things.

Comment: @user15775693 I don't have time for QnA, but I can tell you when I interned almost 4 years ago I had to learn React-native *and* Javascript. Official React docs and google/stackoverflow were my tutors. Other than these, practice what you read about. Create [codesandboxes](https://codesandbox.io/) to quickly standup a workspace and prototype concepts so you can play around and see how stuff works, without the hassle of setting up or configuring a local environment.

Comment: @user15775693 If you do have new stackoverflow questions/issues though, do feel free to tag (@ me) in a previous question (like right here in this comment thread) with a link to your post, and if/when I'm able to respond make sure to come back and clean up your "tagging" comment.

Comment: Thank you so much in advance. I will tag you when i am in stuck @Drew Reese :)

Comment: Hello @Drew Reese . Can you help me with this https://snack.expo.io/ZeFPYnGGH  I am trying to change it into function based. could you correct me please

Comment: @user15775693 Sorry if I was ambiguous, I meant ask an entirely new question as a post on stackoverflow, and then ping me here. You'll get more eyes on your question more quickly that way. Your expo snack fails to run. Seems `Log` is just a function declared somewhere, you just invoke it (`Log('loadSettings Error => ', err)`) though following naming conventions it should be camelCased (`log('loadSettings Error => ', err)`). The `callback()` function should be called from a `useEffect` with a dependency on `currentTheme` state value. `useState` state updater function doesn't have a callback.